# Run OpenAI env.render() as inline graphic in Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, openai-gym

I would like to render my OpenAI gym environments inline in Jupyter. Basically I am looking for a magic action like the one for matplotlib

```
%matplotlib inline
```

But for `gym`. Is this possible, if so, how?

Comment: I don't know about OpenAI gym, but you can display arbitrary things inline by getting the (HTML, PNG, etc.) data and using the machinery in [IPython.display](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html). If module authors want to develop closer integration for their objects, see the docs [here](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/integrating.html#rich-display).